How to run celery worker and beat with RabbitMq in docker container with MYSQL
Docker File
FROM python:3.10-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y gcc libcurl4-gnutls-dev librtmp-dev libnss3 libnss3-dev wget cron pkg-config \
    libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev build-essential \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/

EXPOSE 8000

Docker Compose file
version: '3.9'

services:
  vineCal_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_NAME}
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3 vinecalc_server.wsgi:application
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - vineCal_db
    networks:
      - my_network

  celery_worker:
    build: .
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A vinecalc_server worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - vineCal_db
    networks:
      - my_network

  celery_beat:
    build: .
    entrypoint: celery
    command: -A vinecalc_server beat --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - vineCal_db
    networks:
      - my_network

volumes:
  data:

networks:
  my_network:

Error Logs
vinecalc-server-celery_worker-1  | Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
vinecalc-server-celery_worker-1  | Try 'celery --help' for help.
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
vinecalc-server-celery_worker-1  | 
vinecalc-server-celery_worker-1  | 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | Try 'celery --help' for help.
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | Unable to load celery application.
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | While trying to load the module vinecalc_server the following error occurred:
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 389, in find_app
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     found = sym.app
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | AttributeError: module 'vinecalc_server' has no attribute 'app'
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 394, in find_app
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     found = sym.celery
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | AttributeError: module 'vinecalc_server' has no attribute 'celery'
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 383, in find_app
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 64, in symbol_by_name
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return getattr(module, cls_name) if cls_name else module
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | AttributeError: module 'vinecalc_server' has no attribute 'celery'
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 279, in ensure_connection
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     self.connect()
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 256, in get_new_connection
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 195, in __init__
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | MySQLdb.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown server host 'vineCal_db' (-3)")
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | 
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 58, in convert
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return find_app(value)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 401, in find_app
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return find_app(
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 386, in find_app
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     sym = imp(app)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 109, in import_from_cwd
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return imp(module, package=package)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/app/vinecalc_server/celery.py", line 17, in <module>
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     tenant_queues = [
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 400, in __iter__
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     self._fetch_all()
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1928, in _fetch_all
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 91, in __iter__
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     results = compiler.execute_sql(
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1572, in execute_sql
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     cursor = self.connection.cursor()
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 320, in cursor
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return self._cursor()
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 296, in _cursor
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     self.ensure_connection()
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 278, in ensure_connection
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     with self.wrap_database_errors:
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 279, in ensure_connection
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     self.connect()
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in connect
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 256, in get_new_connection
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 121, in Connect
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 195, in __init__
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    |     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
vinecalc-server-celery_beat-1    | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown server host 'vineCal_db' (-3)")

same Error for vinecalc-server-celery_worker-1

The actual problem is the very last line
Unknown server host 'vineCal_db' (-3)

If you look in the Compose file, the database container doesn't have a networks: block, but the other containers do.  This means the database container is connected to an automatically-created network named default, where the other containers are only connected to the manually-created my_network.  Since they're not on the same network, they can't talk to each other.
For almost all Compose applications, the default network that Compose creates on its own is just fine, and the easiest setup is to delete all of the networks: blocks in the entire file.

(I'd also consider removing the potentially-problematic volumes: that hide the image's code, combining entrypoint: and command: into just command:, and renaming the database container to just db.  You may need an extended form of depends_on: to wait for the database to actually be running.  Don't forget to set a standard CMD in the Dockerfile, probably to launch the Django server; that container won't need a Compose command: override.)

Ok got it let me try
